# Way to use self in method default argument?

Tags: python

For a method of a class I want the following behaviour

```
>>class A:
>>    def __init__(self, x):
>>        self.x = x
>>    def func(self, x = self.x):
>>        print(x)
>>a = A(5)
>>a.func(2)
2
>>a.func()
5
```

But I get this error for the declaration of `func()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in A
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Is there a recommended way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sentinel value; `None` typically suffices.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def func(self, x=None):
        if x is None:
            x = self.x
        print(x)
```

If, for whatever reason, `None` could be a valid argument, you can create your own sentinel.

```
_sentinel = object()
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def func(self, x=_sentinel):
        if x is _sentinel:
            x = self.x
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer to `self` in a function declaration, since at that point `self` indeed doesn't exist (as the error says). The idiomatic way is:

```
def func(self, x = None):
    if x is None:
        x = self.x
    print(x)
```

Or perhaps:

```
def func(self, x = None):
    print(x or self.x)
```

(Though note that *falsey* isn't the same as `None` and may hence behave differently.)

Comment: Don't use `not`; what if x is 0 or false or an empty list or any other value that might be treated as False? You are specifically looking for the exact object `None`.

Comment: Hence my footnote.

Comment: Explaining why it is a bad idea doesn't really justify suggesting it in the first place.

Comment: Depending on what you expect valid inputs to this function to be and what behaviour it should display for invalid values, it may be entirely reasonable.

Comment: None of which is present in the question; you are making unwarranted assumptions.